# How to override Django view that has a namespaced url pattern?

Tags: python, django

I'm using external application called `foo` which I mostly like, but I need to extend functionality of one specific view called `Bar`. Normally, I'd just put my extended view in `urls.py` before `include('foo.urls')` and name it the same, so that resolver hits it first:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^foo/path_to_bar$', CustomBar.as_view(), name='bar'),
    url(r'^foo/$', include('foo.urls')),
    ...
]
```

The problem is, `foo` uses namespaced urls everywhere, so the view in question is actually referred to by `foo:bar` and the `include()` declaration above should actually be:

```
include('foo.urls', namespace='foo', app_name='foo')
```

This is apparently great for resuable apps, but I have hard time finding the way to override this view in my project. Are there any means to do so, without rewriting all calls to `reverse()` and uses of `{% url %}` in `foo`? That would esentially amount to forking the app and defeat the purpose of reusing a view in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understand the problem. `{% url 'foo:foo' %}` will match the url pattern in the app, and return `/foo/path_to_bar/`. That URL will then be matched by your custom URL pattern. The name of the URL pattern of your custom view shouldn't matter.

That won't work if the original app uses a different URL than `path_to_bar`. In this case you still don't have to change all the calls to `reverse` - just create your own `my_foo_urls.py`, duplicate the contents of `foo/urls.py`, and include that instead.